Does a lever move a mass faster if the fulcrum is closer to the applied force?
Assume a lever where there is a mass $m$ at a distance $a$ from the fulcrum, and on the other side of the fulcrum a constant force $F+mg$ is applied at a distance $b$ from the fulcrum. Then by moments (cancelling the $mg$ force on each side), we calculate that the overall force exerted on the mass is equal to $\frac{Fb}{a}$.
Now since the lever is placed on the ground, the lever can only be pushed a certain distance $d$ before it reaches the ground: $d$ is entirely dependent on the height of the fulcrum and not $a$ or $b$. Then by similar triangles (or sectors) we see that the other side of the lever moves a distance $\frac{da}{b}$.
As expected by conservation of energy and the transmission of moment, we get that the work done on $m$ is equal to $Fd$, and this is regardless of $a$ and $b$. So the kinetic energy of the mass should be the same regardless.
However, simple experiments with a ruler as the lever show that a small mass is launched significantly higher when I drop a book on the other side when the distance to the pivot is shorter.
What is the explanation for this? I initially attempted this experiment just using my finger to push down the ruler, and thought that perhaps when the distance is shorter and the ruler is "harder" to push, that my muscles have a longer time to get to maximum force, however I mitigated this factor by using the book, yet the results are the same. Can anybody suggest the flaw in either my analysis or my experiment?


we calculate that the overall force exerted on the mass is equal to $\frac{Fb}{a}$.

Probably not a huge problem in this case, but as long as the lever has mass, then the moments are not the same when the lever is accelerating.

However, simple experiments with a ruler as the lever show that a small mass is launched significantly higher when I drop a book on the other side when the distance to the pivot is shorter.

Dropping a book on a lever is not a source of constant force.
If you drop a book on a table, high forces are created sufficient to decelerate the book rapidly.   If you drop a book on a feather (in mid-air), the book is barely decelerated at all and very little force is developed (until it strikes the ground).
The same happens with your lever.   When the book side of the lever arm is short, the lever can develop large forces to decelerate the book.   When that side of the lever arm is long, the book will not be able to apply the same force.
Constant forces make some physics problems easy to calculate.   But it is very difficult to create constant forces in dynamic situations.

So is my analaysis correct - if a theoretically constant force could be applied, would the resulting speed of the mass be unchanged regardless of the pivot point?

... minus energy into to the lever, minus the difference in potential energy for the mass due to the swing ending at different heights, yes.
